# Spring How to set a dynamic prefix on login url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication

I have a spring application that always start with a dynamic prefix. This is because I need that prefix to make some internal configurations. The problem is that when I try to set my login page, it is imposible to pass that prefixe and making work. How can I set the dymanic prefix to my login page?

This is part of my AppController where I am assigning the Request Mapping to have my prefix.

**AppCotroler.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/{myDynamicPrefix}")
public class AppController {

    ...... @PathVariable String myDynamicPrefix // To ascces to the variable
}
```

And this is part of my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter where the login page is asigned.

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MyDBAuthenticationService myDBAauthenticationService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/{myDynamicPrefix}/login").permitAll();
        // If no login, it will redirect to /login page.
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/{myDynamicPrefix}/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')");
        http.authorizeRequests().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

        // Config for Login Form
        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()//
                // Submit URL of login page.
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") // Submit URL
                .loginPage("/{myDynamicPrefix}/login")// 
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/userInfo")//
                .failureUrl("/{myDynamicPrefix}/login?error=true")//
                .usernameParameter("username")//
                .passwordParameter("password")
                // Config for Logout Page
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/{myDynamicPrefix}/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/{myDynamicPrefix}/logoutSuccessful");

    }
```

The think is that `.antMatchers("/{myDynamicPrefix}/login")` and `.antMatchers("/","/{myDynamicPrefix}/**")` are working normally but `.loginPage("/{myDynamicPrefix}/login")` is not working at all.

This is an example of how I want the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/MyPrefix/MyPage
```

Comment: do you want different themes/designs for the loginpage or what is your intention?

Comment: Can you move your myDynamicPrefix to the url parameter, e.g. ```/login?parameter=myDynamicPrefix```