# Spring how to define a login page URL as a regex pattern

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a spring application that use dynamic prefix as a language path variable. I have the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283236/spring-how-to-set-a-dynamic-prefix-on-login-url).

- /en/user/login.html
- /de/user/login.html
- /{lang}/user/login.html

##### UserSecurityConfiguration

```
public static class UserSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        ...

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            ...

            http.anonymous().principal("user-guest").authorities("GUEST").and()
                .regexMatcher("\\/(en|de)\\/user\\/.*")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .regexMatchers("\\/(en|de)\\/user\\/app-assets\\/.*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/{lang}/user/login.html")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/{lang}/user/login.html", true).permitAll()
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/{lang}/user/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/{lang}/user/login.html")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/{lang}/user/login.html")
                .and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me-admin").key("appAdminSecret")
                .userDetailsService(adminDetailsService()).tokenValiditySeconds(86400);
            http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
            http.csrf().disable();

        }
}
```

The problem is that the `"/{lang}/user/login.html"` pattern is interpreted as a string value, and it's impossible to set a dynamic pattern and make it work. How can I set a dynamic prefix as language code for my login and logout pages?

Comment: why would you have a seperate endpoint for each login instead of taking in the language selection as a query param? `/user/login.html?lang=en`

Comment: because it looks ugly, I would like to find a solution with path variable.

Comment: I would say the opposite, having the language as you have defined it does not follow rest